# Rails paperclip - Upload original image and thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3, paperclip, thumbnails

I'd like to upload not only the original image, even create a thumbnail and store both files in S3.

I understood that with the following lines it was fine:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:original => "100x100>", 
                                    :thumb => "100x100"},
                :path => "images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => {
                    :bucket => "xxxxxxxx",
                    :access_key_id => "xxxxxxx",
                    :secret_access_key => "xxxxxxx"
                }
end
```

But it only saves the original file. What's wrong?

Comment: If you haven't yet found a solution, try checking your config files.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was the paperclip version. After update it to last one, the problem had desapered.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
:style_:basename.:extension
```

try this

```
:style.:extension
```

Comment: No, only saves a file called original.png